# T-SQL column with past month date as name

Tags: sql-server, date

I am trying to name a column with the first day of the past month so if I am in March the column name should be '2021-01-02' (yyyy-mm-dd), I would prefer that the query wouldn't by dynamic but if there is no other way I will accept such a solution, the column that should show the date is the balance one, see below query:

```
SELECT 
    --'Turnover' as "Group Mask"
    CASE 
       WHEN LEFT(t0.FatherNum, 1) = 'R' THEN 'REV' 
       ELSE 'Other' 
    END AS "Classification",
    t0."AcctName" "Account Name",
    SUM(t1.Debit - t1.Credit) * -1 AS Balance
FROM 
    OACT t0 -- G/L Accounts
INNER JOIN 
    JDT1 t1 ON T0."AcctCode" = T1."Account"
WHERE
    t0."GroupMask" = 4
    AND t1.RefDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -2)) 
                       AND EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)
GROUP BY 
    t0."AcctCode", t0."AcctName", t1.RefDate, t0.FatherNum
```

Comment: Any particular query always produces a result set with a fixed "shape" - the number of columns, their *names* and their types. So, no, you won't avoid having to construct a new query on the fly, a.k.a. dynamic SQL. On the other hand, is there a reason this name has to be fixed by the *query* rather than whatever is consuming it (e.g. an application, report builder, etc)

Comment: Hi Damien, I am not sure i understand your question, are you asking why i don't want a dynamic query?

Comment: No, I'm saying you cannot avoid it. It's an unfulfillable requirement because column names are *fixed* as part of any particular query. But I was suggesting you could avoid it completely if you rename a column with a fixed name at a higher level in your application/report builder.

Comment: Ah ok, using the resources of the report builder to have the date built there, i don't think it will work since I am using powerbi

Comment: PowerBI uses DAX as an underlying query language, and renaming table columns is certainly possible. You shouldn't need to, however, if you offer up the month as a column *value*, rather than the column *name*. You can set up your visualizations to use that value as the label, rather than the column name. This is useful even if the value is the same for all rows.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: Hi Jeroen the problem is that i can't hard code a month it would have to be interactive, so if i am in March it should show February date on the column

Comment: Column names can't be defined by an expression: `{expression} AS DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE())` would error. If you *must* have a dynamic name for a column, you must use dynamic SQL, however, if it's only one column that has a dynamic name you are far better off having the presentation layer simply change the header for that column in the application, not the SQL.